# dict match the function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I counter a problem:

```
dic={'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3}

def a_Item():
    print('a')

def b_Item():
    print('b')

def c_Item():
    print('c')

def main(url): 
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if url == v:
           a_Item()

main(1)
```

As you see, I have a dictionary and three function. I have a parameter like url in the main. if the url=1, I can find the matched key(a) in dic, finally I want to call the function a_Item.

url=1 --> key=a --> a_Item(function)

url=2 --> key=b --> b_Item(function)

In the code above I can only call the function a_Item().Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `globals()` like so:

```
def main(url): 
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if url == v:
            globals()[k + '_Item']()
```

Comment: Honestly, although this answers the literal question being asked, I think it's not good to encourage this use of globals.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it really depends; manually setting up a dictionary typing in all those key value pairs is fine for 3 items, but what if it's 100 functions? Then it's error-prone, difficult to read and a nightmare to maintain. Whereas directly operating on the name maps what is meant and scales easily. Out of interest, what is a legit use of globals in your book?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a dictionary *to the functions*:

```
dic={1:a_Item,
    2:b_Item,
    3:c_Item}
```

And then simply:

```
dic[url]()
```

Notice I am using the call operator: `()`

Also note this wouldn't be strictly equivalent to iterating over the key-value pairs. If you do, you can call more than one function, since values do not have to be unique. The above method calls exactly one function (or none if there is a `KeyError`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dic={'a':[1, a_Item()],
'b':[2, b_Item()],
'c':[3, c_Item()]}

def a_Item():
    print('a')

def b_Item():
    print('b')

def c_Item():
    print('c')

def main(url): 
    for v in dic:
        if dic[v][0] == url:
            dic[v][1]


main(1)
main(2)
main(3)
```

As it seems like you don't need a, b, c in dictionary so you can create a direct combination of 1 with a_Item() and 2 with b_Item() So better approach will be:

```
dic = {1:a_Item(),
2:b_Item(),
3:c_Item()}

def a_Item():
    print('a')

def b_Item():
    print('b')

def c_Item():
    print('c')

def main(url): 
    for v in dic:
        if v == url:
            dic[v]


main(1)
main(2)
main(3)
```